# Share Intranet through VPNs

Tags: networking, windows, vpn

Site (#S1) has a internal computer quiz system of the PCs in the subnet of 192.168.8.0/24, the web server is located on 192.168.8.2.

Those PCs do not connect to Internet. There is a PC (#A) joined to the subnet 192.168.8.0/24 and dual-homed to subnet 192.168.0.0/24 that connects to a router(#R1) to the Internet. Router(#R1) is provided by the ISP and cannot set port forward.

In order to connect to the internal PCs in the subnet 192.168.8.0/24 , I use following steps:

1. On Site (#S2), where the ISP router allows port forward, I setup a VPN server (#V1) on PC (#B), using subnet 192.168.7.0/24
2. One Site (#S1), in PC(#A), use VPN to connect to (#V1) and get an IP, (e.g. 192.168.7.245)
3. I setup a VPN server (#V2) in PC(#A) to subnet 192.168.8.0/24

So now I can access the computer quiz system from the Internet by:

1. Connect to VPN server (#V1) and get a 192.168.7.0/24 IP
2. Connect to VPN server (#V2) on IP 192.168.7.245 and get a 192.168.8.0/24 IP
3. Access the 192.168.8.2 web server

My question is whether I can have any configuration (routing table?) in PC (#A) or PC (#B), so that someone can access the 192.168.8.0/24 network by connecting to VPN server (#V1) ONLY? which means someone can access 192.168.8.0/24 subnet from 192.168.7.0/24 subnet.

Comment: Let me guess, you are trying to complete your school tests from home where you can access the Internet and look up answers?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you need to set up VPN#2 is because PC#B cannot receive incoming connections, but must reach outwards first, which is what you're doing with the VPN chain. The only way this will work with the limitation on Site 1's router is for PC#B to reach out first. You can do this with reverse tunnels, or with VPNs, like you're doing.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that the limitation is PC#A cannot receive incoming connections. But since PC#B can access the intranet 192.168.8.2 after the VPN#2 on PC#A, are there any workaround can let the User from VPN#1 can access the 192.168.8.2 through PC#B, instead of another connection VPN#2 needed...

Comment: Can PC#B share the VPN#2(Access) with the user from VPN#1?